# Why is the potential energy of spring negative while it's positive for a dipole?

Tags: potential-energy, conventions, spring, dipole

> Potential Energy is the work done **against** the conservative force

As the definition suggests , for a spring
$$
U= -\int F \cdot \mathrm{d}x
\,.$$

But for a dipole placed in an electric field
$$
U= \int \tau \cdot \mathrm{d}\theta
\,.$$

**Why is negative sign not used in case of dipole ?**

Comment: Tip: use dollar symbols to enclose formulas, they will display laTEX format.

Comment: You might, perhaps, start by thinking about the negative sign in the spring equation that you quote. Is $\mathbf{F}$ the force exerted on or by the spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in potential energy is defined as either being the work done by an external force in changing the positions of charges $\Delta U = + \int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} \vec F_{\rm external} \cdot d \vec r$ or minus the work done by the electric field in changing the positions of the charges $\Delta U = - \int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} \vec F_{\rm field} \cdot d \vec r$.

You will note that because $\vec F_{\rm external} + \vec F_{\rm field} = 0$ all you are doing is either putting a negative sign outside the integral$- \int  \vec F_{\rm field} \cdot d \vec r$ or inside the integral $\int (- \vec F_{\rm field}) \cdot d \vec r = \int  \vec F_{\rm external} \cdot d \vec r $

If the initial state is one with the potential energy defined as zero then those equations give you the potential energy of the final state.

---

With your dipole equation for potential energy the definitions for potential energy stay exactly the same and in the equation that you have quoted  $U = \int \tau \, d\theta$, the torque $\tau$ is the magnitude of the torque as is shown below.

An electric dipole with point charges $\pm q$ separated by a distance $d$ have a dipole moment $\vec p = q \vec d$ where the displacement $\vec d$ is in the directions from the negative charge to the positive charge.

[image]

In an electric field $\vec E$ the torque on the dipole is

$\vec \tau = \vec p \times \vec E = pE \sin \theta\, (-\hat z)$

where $\hat z$ is the unit vector out of the screen and the angle between the electric field direction and the electric dipole direction is $\theta$ then the magnitude of the torque on the dipole is $pE \sin \theta$

The work done by the electric field in rotating the dipole from $\theta_{\rm initial}$ to $\theta_{\rm final}$ is

$\int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} \vec \tau \cdot d\vec \theta'= \int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} [pE \sin \theta' \,(-\hat z)]\cdot  [d\theta'\,\hat z]= -\int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} pE \sin \theta' \, d\theta'$

and minus this quantity is the change in potential energy

$\Delta U = + \int ^{\rm final}_{\rm initial} pE \sin \theta' \, d\theta'$

If you were considering the external torque you would still have the same integral for the change in potential energy which is your $\int \tau \,d\theta$ equation with $\tau$ as the magnitude of the torque.

If the lowest potential energy state when $\theta =0$ is taken as the zero of potential energy then the potential energy at an angle $\theta$ is  $U = \int ^\theta _0 pE \sin \theta' \, d\theta' = pE(1-\cos \theta) $.

It is sometimes convenient to have the  $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ position as the zero of potential energy and then $U = -\vec p \cdot \vec E$